# Passing dynamic javascript values using Url.action()

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Could anyone please tell how to pass dynamic values using Url.action().

Something Like,

```
var firstname="abc";
var username = "abcd";
location.href = '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Display", "Customer", new { uname = firstname ,name = username}))';
```

firstname, username is not getting reffered inside the Url.action() method.

How to pass these dynamic values using Url.action()?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The `@Url.Action()` method is proccess on the `server-side`, so you cannot pass a `client-side` value to this function as a parameter. You can concat the `client-side` variables with the `server-side` url generated by this method, which is a string on the output. Try something like this:

```
let firstName = "John";
let userName = "Smith";
location.href = '@Url.Action("Display", "Customer")?uname=' + firstName + '&name=' + userName ;
```

The `@Url.Action("Display", "Customer")` is processed on the `server-side` and the rest of the string is processed on the `client-side`, concatenating the result of the `server-side` method with the `client-side`.

Comment: I ended up adding an onclick event to a <a> element which appended to the href attribute which was set using Url.Action

Comment: But what if without that parameter the path is different?

Answer (score 11):

This answer might not be 100% relevant to the question. But it does address the problem.
I found this simple way of achieving this requirement. Code goes below:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Display", "Customer")?custId={{cust.Id}}"></a>
```

In the above example **{{cust.Id}}** is an AngularJS variable. However one can replace it with a JavaScript variable.

I haven't tried passing multiple variables using this method but I'm hopeful that also can be appended to the Url if required.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is:

```
  onClick= 'location.href="/controller/action/"+paramterValue'
```

Comment: do you really need an onclick event? could you do the same thing with the form's `action` attribute...

Answer (score 1):

In my case it worked great just by doing the following:

### The Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(int custNum)
{
    // Some magic code here...
}
```

### Create the form with no action:

```
<form id="frmSomething" method="post">
    <div>
        <!-- Some magic html here... -->
    </div>
    <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

### Set button click event to trigger submit after adding the action to the form:

```
var frmSomething= $("#frmSomething");
var btnSubmit= $("#btnSubmit");
var custNum = 100;

btnSubmit.click(function()
{
    frmSomething.attr("action", "/Home/DoSomething?custNum=" + custNum);

    btnSubmit.submit();
});
```

Hope this helps vatos!

Comment: Maybe it would be more future-proof if you could replace the string `/Home/DoSomething` with `@Url.Action("DoSomething", "TheController")`. That way if you rename your controller and/or action, your related url would still stay valid.