# Redirecting a page with javascript concatenates values to the URL instead of redirecting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a dropdown that allows users to select a data feed to view. The first time a user selects one, my URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost/DataFeeds/Viewer/1
```

On the second selection, it looks like this:

```
http://localhost/DataFeeds/Viewer/1/2
```

That's obviously not correct. The `1` should be replaced with the `2`.

Here's the code that causes it:

```
$('select#ID').change(function () {                
    window.location.replace("@Url.Action("Viewer", "DataFeeds")/" + $(this).val());
});
```

I've already tried

`window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Viewer", "DataFeeds")/" + $(this).val();`

but that does the same thing.

All suggestions appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're concatenating the two strings rather than replacing the 1. try replacing the one using RegExp or similar.

Comment: In your example ```window.location.href = url``` what is the value of url? Can you put some debugger statements in to see what is happening at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following response is wrong. window.location.replace() does redirect, my bad !

Actually window.location.replace() is the same as window.location = url, with the small difference that replace() removes the old location from the browser history, and thus not making it possible to use the back button.

---

Bad response:

You are replacing not assigning

```
window.location = window.location.replace("@Url.Action("Viewer", "DataFeeds")/" + $(this).val());


// This does not redirect it just grabs the string of the location and modifies it
window.location.replace("@Url.Action("Viewer", "DataFeeds")/" + $(this).val());

// is the same as doing
var redirectTo = window.location.replace("@Url.Action("Viewer", "DataFeeds")/" + $(this).val());

// you still need to do
window.location = redirectTo;
```

---

However

If it doens't work like you said, then replace("@Url.Action("Viewer", "DataFeeds")/" + $(this).val()); is flawed.

Comment: Nope ..change to document.location ! :)

Comment: Never mind, my firebug is acting up and i was saying switch from window.location to document.location ..but never mind

Comment: Well, it redirected right ? ..that just means your replace expression is wrong.

Comment: Then replace("@Url.Action("Viewer", "DataFeeds")/" + $(this).val()); is flawed. console.log() it to see what you are actually replacing

Answer (score 0):

There is another answer on stack overflow which answers this question. I was having the same issue and found that I needed to use the ?name= syntax mentioned here:
[Passing dynamic javascript values using Url.action()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112055/passing-dynamic-javascript-values-using-url-action/15112223)

instead of using this:

```
$('select#ID').change(function () {                
    window.location.replace("@Url.Action("Viewer", "DataFeeds")/" + $(this).val());
});
```

try using something like this:

```
$('select#ID').change(function () {                
    window.location.replace("@Url.Action("Viewer", "DataFeeds")?id=" + $(this).val());
});
```

When using the ?name= syntax, the ending no longer concatenated for me.