# pass value of a Ext.NET hidden field to Action method as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ext.net

how can i access a hidden field value in Action methods parameter
please refer following code

```
Url.Action("action","controller",new {para_name=hidden_field_value})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing dynamic javascript values using Url.action()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112055/passing-dynamic-javascript-values-using-url-action)

Comment: i have taken the value inside @ViewBag.Item and i want to assign this value as a parameter to the Action Above and dont want to send it as a querystring parameter

Comment: you assign the value from ViewBag.Item to a hidden field, then later you want to pass it to Url.Action as a parameter?

Comment: no.i have taken value in both a ViewBag and a hidden field.tried to access both with no success yet

Comment: there is only one way to do it, check my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution, first set the value to hidden field inside above `getCmbCountry()` function
and then sent this hidden field value as a `EXT.NET StoreParameter` as below

```
.Params(new StoreParameter { Name="countryCode", Value="App.hdnCountry.getValue()", Mode=ParameterMode.Raw})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Your code in the comment only assigns the value "country" to ViewBag.Country, which means it will not work.

again your only solution is to use the following

```
var url = '@Url.Action("action", "controller")?country=' + Ext.getCmp("CmbCountry").value
```

you say

> i want to assign this value as a parameter to the Action Above and
>   dont want to send it as a query-string parameter

but that's exactly what the `Url.Action` method do, if you observe the result of the `Url.Action` method you will see that it is one and the same

Comment: i tried this but the `ViewBag.Item` is returning the name rather than value

Comment: here is my code    `var country="";
    var getCmbCountry = function () {
        country = Ext.getCmp("CmbCountry").value;
        App.hdnCountry.value=country;
        @(ViewBag.Country="country")
    };`