# How to put asp.net MVC code in AngularJS file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

From this thread [Passing dynamic javascript values using Url.action()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112055/passing-dynamic-javascript-values-using-url-action), how can something like that be put into a javascript file?  This would be the AngularJS controller file.

From the example above, the following can be used in an AngularJS controller defined in the _Layout.cshtml script tags:

```
var firstname = "abc";
var username = "abcd";
location.href = '@Url.Action("Display", "Customer")?uname=' + firstname + '&name=' + username;
```

The issue is that the asp.net MVC code doesn't play well when put into a javascript file.  It works fine when in the _Layout.cshtml script tags.  But not in a JS file.

Comment: Since ASP.Net MVC cannot not pre process, JS file, i think this is not possible. Check this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389649/possible-to-access-mvc-viewbag-object-from-javascript-file

Answer (score 0):

For scenarios like these, I do something like the following

Say in my Angular controller I need to pass a value of the LoggedInUser, for which I have a server side Helper class available.

So in my Razor view I do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.loggedInUser = '@MyHelper.LoggedInUser()';
</script>
```

And then access this global variable in my Angular controller.

Comment: Ok.  I guess that doesn't really help since the majority of my code will still be in the _Layout.cshtml and not in any JS file.  It would be best to keep all JS that works with Razor in the _Layout.cshtml rather than trying to force it into a JS file.  Would you agree?

Comment: No. I would go for JS to be in seperate JS files.