# use Url.Action with dynamic values

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have following link

```
var selectedValue = "someDynamicValue";
var selectedId = 100;
window.location.href = '/Home/' + selectedValue + '/' + selectedId;
```

how can I use `@Url.Action` instead of above link generation?

Comment: You can't pass dynamic values but you can do something like the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112055/passing-dynamic-javascript-values-using-url-action?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like this:

```
var selectedValue = "someDynamicValue";
var selectedId = 100;
var href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { selectedValue = "_selectedValue_", selectedId = "_selectedId_"})';
href = href.replace('_selectedValue_', selectedValue);
href = href.replace('_selectedId_', selectedId);
window.location.href = href;
```