# ASP.Net MVC: How could i pass js array to mvc action by @Url.Action()

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

We know that we can pass js variable value to mvc action but how could i pass js array to mvc action ?

So my question is how could i pass js array to mvc action by @Url.Action() ?

### please see my sample code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(string id, string deptno, list<PdfInputs> PdfInputs)
{
    // Some magic code here...
}

var id = "10";
var deptno = "C001";

var PdfInputs = [];
for(inti=0;i<=totalbol-1;i++)
{
    var PdfInput = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: 46
    };
}
PdfInputs.push(BOLPdfInput);

location.href = '@Url.Action("DoSomething", "Customer")?id=' + id + '&deptno=' + deptno;
```

my mvc action will download pdf at client and that is why i use

```
location.href = '@Url.Action("DoSomething", "Customer")?id=' + id + '&deptno=' + deptno;
```

please guide me.

Comment: You method is marked `[HttpPost]` - you cannot navigate to a POST method (you need to submit a form). And if it was a GET method, then the url need to be `../DoSomething?id=10&deptno=C001&PdfInputs[0].firstName=John&PdfInputs[0].lastName=Doe&PdfInputs[0].age=46&PdfInputs[0].firstName=xxx.......` but you would likely exceed the query string limit and throw an exception if you did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/RRwK1K

View

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tut123</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#theButton").click(function () {
                var id = "10";
                var deptno = "C001";

                var PdfInputs = [];
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                    PdfInputs.push({
                        firstName: "John",
                        lastName: "Doe",
                        age: 46
                    });

                }
                var json = JSON.stringify(PdfInputs);
                location.href = '@Url.Action("theActionPassArray", "Home")?json=' + json;
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="theButton" value="Go" />
    @*credit to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112055/passing-dynamic-javascript-values-using-url-action*@
    @if (ViewBag.Data != null)
    {
        <span>The data sent to the server was:</span>@ViewBag.Data
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
public class PassArray
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lasttName { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult theActionPassArray(string json)
    {
        /turn json passed value into array
        //You need to get NewtonSoft.JSON
        PassArray[] arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PassArray[]>(json);
        //put breakpoint here
        ViewBag.Data = json;
        return View("Tut123");        }

    public ActionResult Tut123()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: @KendoStarter I changed my post and added a fiddle you can click on.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can pass JSON string from array with `@Url.Action()` helper using query string parameter like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var id = "10";
    var deptno = "C001";

    var PdfInputs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < totalbol; i++)
    {
        PdfInputs.push({
            firstName: "John",
            lastName: "Doe",
            age: 46
        });
    }

    location.href = '@Url.Action("DoSomething", "Customer")?id=' + id + '&deptno=' + deptno + '&PdfInputs=' + JSON.stringify(PdfInputs);
})
</script>
```

However I strongly discourage this practice because passed JSON string may exceeds query string limit if the array has large amount of data. Additionally, you cannot use `@Url.Action()` helper for action method marked with `[HttpPost]` attribute (it only works for `GET` method), hence I recommend to use `jQuery.ajax()` to pass `PdfInputs` array as `List<PdfInputs>` & `TempData`/`Session` state variable to store file contents, then download PDF file using `HttpGet` controller action as provided below:

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var id = "10";
    var deptno = "C001";

    var PdfInputs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < totalbol; i++)
    {
        PdfInputs.push({
            firstName: "John",
            lastName: "Doe",
            age: 46
        });
    }

    $('#buttonid').click(function () {
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '@Url.Action("DoSomething", "Customer")',
             // traditional: true,
             data: $.param({ id: id, deptno: deptno, pdfInputs: PdfInputs }, true),
             success: function (result) {
                 location.href = '@Url.Action("Download", "ControllerName")?id=' + id;
             },
             error: function (err) {
                 // error handling
             }
         });
    });
})
</script>
```

**Controller (DoSomething Action)**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(string id, string deptno, List<PdfInputs> pdfInputs)
{
    // Some magic code here...

    // Save file to TempData or Session state
    byte[] fileContent = fileStreamInstance.ToArray();

    TempData["FileToDownload"] = fileContent;

    return Json("Success");
}
```

**Controller (Download Action)**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Download(string id)
{
    string fileName = "yourfilename.pdf";
    // other code here
    if (TempData["FileToDownload"] != null)
    {
        byte[] content = TempData["FileToDownload"] as byte[];
        return File(content, "application/pdf", fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```