# use @Url.Action with parameter in click event jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to use @Url.Action to reach a MVC ASP.NET controller using the buton' click event and jQuery, so far this works for me

```
 $("#btnEneviar").click(function (e) {
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action(actionName: "TipoEvento", controllerName: "Home")';
        });
```

but now I need to send a parameter to the controller using the route, this is my code

```
 $("#btnEnviar").click(function (e)
        {    
            var valorAccion = $('#Table tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)').text();
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Solicitud", "Home", new { valor = valorAccion })';
        });
```

but I got the error: "the name valorAccion does not exits in the current context"

could you please help me to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing dynamic javascript values using Url.action()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112055/passing-dynamic-javascript-values-using-url-action)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing server-side and client-side technologies so you can't really do it how you want to do it, but you can get around it by doing it like this:

```
    $("#btnEnviar").click(function (e) {
        var valorAccion = $('#Table tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)').text();
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Solicitud", "Home")?valor=' + valorAccion;
    });
```